# Iterator throwing NullPointerException inside JSONArray null value

Tags: java, json, arrays

I'm trying to read data from a `JSON` file with the following code:

```
FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(reader);
JSONArray dataName = (JSONArray)jsonObject.get("results");
Iterator it = dataName.iterator();

while (it.hasNext()) {
    JSONObject out = (JSONObject) it.next();
    System.out.printf("Game name: " + out.get("name") + " in plataforms:");
    JSONArray data_plat = (JSONArray) out.get("platforms");

    if (!data_plat.isEmpty()) {
        Iterator it2 = data_plat.iterator();

        while (it2.hasNext()) {
            System.out.printf("I AM HERE");
            JSONObject out_plat = (JSONObject) it2.next();
            System.out.printf("\n- " + out_plat.get("name"));
        } 
    }
}
```

And this code is throwing a `NullPointerException` in this piece:

```
if (!dataPlat.isEmpty());
```

I've analyzed my output and the `JSON` file and this happens because the part i'm reading contains a null value. How can I avoid this?

EDIT: Here's a part of my `JSON`:

```
{
    "name":"FIFA Manager 08",
    "platforms":[
        {
            "api_detail_url":"http:\/\/www.giantbomb.com\/api\/platform\/3045-94\/",
            "id":94,
            "name":"PC",
            "site_detail_url":"http:\/\/www.giantbomb.com\/pc\/3045-94\/",
            "abbreviation":"PC"
        }
    ],
    "resource_type":"game"
},
{
    "name":"FIFA Online 2",
    "platforms":null,
    "resource_type":"game"
},
```

The error is occurring at the bottom in `"platforms":null`

Comment: There's no way for a NPE to happen then. The NPE would have happened at `!data_plat.isEmpty()`.

Comment: please show your json (if not too large)

Comment: have you tried with `if(dataPlat!=null && !dataPlat.isEmpty());`?

Comment: I feel dumb. I tried with !=null and isEmpty() each one alone never both.. Now it works lol. Any explanation why?

Comment: Just using `!= null` should be sufficient, the iterator will take care of it being empty.

Comment: It would appear that `out.get("platforms")` is returning `null`, presumably because the JSON says `{... "platforms" : null ...}`.  (Oh, I see that you finally discovered that.)